# Is it possible to do a case statement comparison on an assigned variable in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, case, variable-assignment

Is it possible I can do the case comparison on the assigned variable 'YRSUMGTHAN75'? When I try to do the `case statement` it barks at me saying 'incorrect syntax near '>''.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT A.DUR, A.TL_QUANTITY,
(SELECT SUM(TL_QUANTITY) FROM PS_TL_RPTD_TIME 
WHERE DUR BETWEEN '01-01-2013' AND '12-31-2013' AND EMPLID = A.EMPLID AND TRC IN   ('JNC', 'SRJ')
HAVING SUM(TL_QUANTITY) > 75) AS YRSUMGTHAN75 

CASE YRSUMGTHAN75 WHEN > 75 THEN 'NewValue'
End

FROM PS_TL_RPTD_TIME A WHERE  A.EMPLID = '10000106052' AND A.DUR > '01-01-2013'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I have edited your post to make your question more clear and to fix your code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand what you're trying to do, but this may be it:

```
select 
    DUR, 
    TL_QUANTITY, 
    case when YRSUMGTHAN75 > 75 then 'NewValue' else 'OldValue' end
from
    (
    SELECT 
        A.DUR, 
        A.TL_QUANTITY,
        (SELECT SUM(TL_QUANTITY) 
         FROM PS_TL_RPTD_TIME 
         WHERE DUR BETWEEN '01-01-2013' AND '12-31-2013' AND EMPLID = A.EMPLID AND TRC IN   ('JNC', 'SRJ')
         HAVING SUM(TL_QUANTITY) > 75) AS YRSUMGTHAN75 
    FROM 
        PS_TL_RPTD_TIME A 
    WHERE  
        A.EMPLID = '10000106052' AND A.DUR > '01-01-2013'
    ) dt
```

If that doesn't help, please construct a *small* artificial example using dummy tables and data to illustrate your question clearly.